# Can't cancel redirection if login fails(devise gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, overriding

I'm using popup registration (usign Bootstrap) and need to cancel redirection if user fails to sign in.

I tried to use this tutorial - http://casperfabricius.com/site/2010/09/30/ajax-sign-in-and-sign-up-with-devise/, but it fails.


I think my problem - CustomFailure class doesn't override standard class.

I have session controller:

```
 class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

 def sign_in_and_redirect(resource_or_scope, resource=nil)
   scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
   resource ||= resource_or_scope
   redirect_url = stored_location_for(scope)
   respond_to do |format|
   format.js do
    sign_in(scope, resource) unless warden.user(scope) == resource
    if redirect_url.present?
      redirect_url = "#{redirect_url}.js" unless redirect_url[-3..-1] == '.js'
      redirect_url += redirect_url.match(/\?/) ? '&' : '?'
      redirect_url += "after_authentication=true"
      redirect_to redirect_url
    else
      render(:update) do |page|
        page << render('/shared/after_authentication')
      end
    end
    end
    format.html { super }
   end
  end
 end
```

In my routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations', :sessions => 'sessions'}
```

I creates custom_failure.rb file in lib folder:

```
   class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
    # Never do http authentication through Devise
   def http_auth?
     false
    end
    def redirect_url
     send(:"new_#{scope}_session_path", :format => (request.xhr? ? 'js' : nil ))
    end
   end
```

and at last in my devise.rb:

```
       require 'custom_failure'
       config.warden do |manager|
         manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
       end
```

Added to my application.rb"

```
      config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

What I'm doing wrong ? Is it problem in age of post or in Failure class?